# Protecting libraries?

Tags: c#, api, networking

I'm currently creating a networking library. I want to make 2 base classes for the library like `TCPServer`, and `UDPServer` that should be accessed by the 1 script only(`Server` Script). I don't want any other script to access the those two scripts. How would I accomplish that?

EDIT: I tried making a parameter in the constructor of the base classes of type dynamic passing in `this`and then the constructor would check if this object passed in is a `Server` object. I'm just asking if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: To broad and not enough information given. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The only surefire way I know of to "protect" code from malicious callers is to not open the opportunity in the first place. Keep the code that needs to be protected on machines that *you* own and control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just use the `internal` keyword to make an object accessible from the current assembly only.